# Stop vim from highlighting "note" in yellow inside SQL comments

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

I am using vim under Ubuntu under the windows WLS. When I edit SQL files, only inside comments - the word "note" is always highlighted with a background yellow color. This includes, for example, if I say `:nohl`, or I search for something etc. And it is just the word "note", nothing else. Not, for example "noted". I would like to stop this behaviour, but am unable to find where it is coming from. The only option so far is to turn off highlighting entirely - but I do like the syntax highlighting for programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
:hi link sqlTodo sqlComment
```

to `.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim` or

Add

```
augroup NO_TODO | au!
    au FileType sql :hi link sqlTodo sqlComment
augroup END
```

to your `.vimrc`.

### Why NOTE, TODO, FIXME and XXX are highlighted?

Usually most vim syntax files have a kind of `Todo` group included into `Comment` to be highlighted differently.

For example, sql filetype has these lines:

```
" Comments:
syn match sqlComment    "--.*$" contains=sqlTodo,@Spell
" Todo:
syn keyword sqlTodo TODO FIXME XXX DEBUG NOTE contained
hi def link sqlTodo     Todo
```

Which includes `sqlTodo` into `sqlComment` and highlights `sqlTodo` as `Todo`.

Comment: I don't yet have the reputation to up vote -- but I used the .vimrc approach and it worked. So thanks.